# what are the limits on the number of envelopes you can publish manually using "Publish using csv" in Docusign application connected to salesforce

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, salesforce-lightning

what are the limits on the number of envelopes you can publish manually using "Publish using .csv" option? I have tried digging into all the documentation provided and there is no mention on the maximum/recommended number of envelopes you can publish using .csv in DocuSign connect. Appreciate your insights/comments on this

Answer (score 0):

Currently its not documented anywhere in public forum but I checked within DocuSign and it is `2000`.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @Amit. Could you please clarify it if is per .csv file or per hour or per day?

Comment: It is per CSV file

Comment: Thank for clarifying Amit!! really appreciate it.